# singleton menu panel not working in extjs 5

Tags: javascript, extjs, menu, extjs4, extjs5

I was working with extjs 4 where i created the menu panels using singleton pattern for number of toolbars and it work well, but when i moved my application from extjs 4 to extjs 5 it stop to work, means the menu panel get hidden when mouse move over it. I have created one sample example on fiddle please give me some solution over this problem.
fiddle link: [singleton menu panel example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/rv2)

Thanks,
Sandy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ext JS 5 menus seem to be linked to their owner components (e.g. button) and cannot be shared between owners. This is why, in your example, the issue happens on the 1st and 2nd panel only but not the last one (3rd) — its button becomes the "legal" owner of the menu and hence it works fine under there.

There is actually no need to share the menu in your example. Instead of repeating the same code three times, leave just **one** docked toolbar, use the menu in only **one** place and make it all smarter. See example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/s1b

UPDATE

If sharing the menu between buttons is a requirement, it can be achieved by using custom button that forcibly makes sure that its menu belongs to itself on each menu show request:

```
Ext.define('SharingMenuButton', {
    extend: 'Ext.button.Button',
    alias: 'widget.sharingmenubutton',
    showMenu: function() {
        if (this.menu.ownerCmp !== this) {
            this.setMenu(this.menu, false);
        }
        return this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

See your example working with that in place: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/s1g

Comment: okay got your point, but i want it for different toolbar it is just a example toolbar has different work on panels but only one menu panel is common between them. Can i do the singleton for this menu panel

Comment: You still can, see update to the answer. I would not recommend it, though. What is the necessity to use singleton menu? You could just create your menu class and use separate instance where required.

Comment: nope in menu panel i have one text area and want to save changes in it, if i create multiple instance i will need to maintain each instance which will broke my app. in another menu panel i have grid which records will change again need to maintain its instance, which was easy in sencha extjs 4 but now it leads my app to crash.

Comment: Why not to share the `textarea` only then? Anyway, the solution should fit now.

Comment: what about the grid menu panel?

Comment: You can just create one instance of everything that needs to be shared (textareas, grids etc.) and insert the instance in as many menus as you need. Also note that the singleton pattern you are using is completely excessive: you could just use `menu: menuPanel` instead of `menu:menu.getInstance()` because `menuPanel === menu.getInstance()` is always `true`.

Comment: okay so you mean i have to create one panel for text area and another for grid and use it in different menu panel of toolbar button. yeah i am defining the panel and creating instance of it on the basis of it created already or not if not then create one instance of it means menuPanel as define and menu.getInstance() for create single instance if not present

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86784/discussion-between-sandy-and-drakees).